# Ruby variable scoping is killing me

Tags: ruby, scope

I have a parser that reads files. Inside a file, you can declare a filename and the parser will go and read that one, then when it is done, pick up right where it left off and continue. This can happen as many levels deep as you want.

Sounds pretty easy so far. All I want to do is print out the file names and line numbers.

I have a class called FileReader that looks like this:

```
class FileReader
    attr_accessor :filename, :lineNumber
    def initialize(filename)
        @filename = filename
        @lineNumber = 0
    end
    def readFile()
        # pseudocode to make this easy
         open @filename
         while (lines)
             @lineNumber = @lineNumber + 1
             if(line startsWith ('File:'))
                 FileReader.new(line).readFile()
             end
             puts 'read ' + @filename + ' at ' + @lineNumber.to_s()
         end
         puts 'EOF'
    end
end
```

Simple enough. So lets say I have a file that refers other files like this. File1->File2->File3. This is what it looks like:

```
read File1 at 1
read File1 at 2
read File1 at 3
read File2 at 1
read File2 at 2
read File2 at 3
read File2 at 4
read File3 at 1
read File3 at 2
read File3 at 3
read File3 at 4
read File3 at 5
EOF
read File3 at 5
read File3 at 6
read File3 at 7
read File3 at 8
EOF
read File2 at 4
read File2 at 5
read File2 at 6
read File2 at 7
read File2 at 8
read File2 at 9
read File2 at 10
read File2 at 11
```

And that doesnt make any sense to me.

```
File 1 has 11 lines
File 2 has 8 lines
File 3 has 4 lines
```

I would assume creating a new object would have its own scope that doesn't affect a parent object.

Comment: Can you rename the question title to something more appropriate?

Comment: Could you post the actual code? The issue is probably in that code so using pseudo-code obfuscates where the real problem lies.

Comment: Having pseudo code and not providing actual input makes it very difficult to help you. My psychic debugger is clouded in a haze. Put executable code or at least actual inputs and output.

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to figure out WTH you are asking about. The question title is about variable scope, but the question is completely unrelated. The question talks about parents, but there is no inheritance in the code. The code you posted is littered with irrelevant bits, but the actual meat of the code is missing. You provide some output, but not the correct one, only the wrong one. You have dependencies on external files but you don't provide the files. You only provide what you think the solution should be, but you don't say what the actual problem is. And last but not least you

Comment: ... don't even format your code properly. *You* want *our* help. Unpaid help, I might add. The least you could do is to extend us the courtesy of spending the 3 milliseconds it takes to hit Alt+Shift+F to format the code (or whatever your editor's shortcut is). It took me almost 10 minutes of staring at your code until I gave up trying to understand it, then another 10 minutes reverse engineering what your are trying to do from the output you posted and almost 20 minutes to figure out what the contents of `File1`, `File2` and `File3` should be. Answering the question then took only 20 seconds.

Comment: ... That's 40 minutes of my time that you could have saved by investing 20 seconds in writing a proper question. And now I don't have time to actually explain the solution.

Comment: Jörg, he is clearly a novice; just like you were once at Ruby and are still so in many other things. Would you want someone treating you as you are treating him if you asked an innocently stupid question about some field you are not proficient in? You don't **have** to help. I understand your frustration but yelling at someone about something of which they are ignorant is a lot like punching a kitten because it doesn't know how to drive. Hopefully you take this in the constructive way in which it was meant.

Answer (score 2):

```
class FileReader
  def initialize(filename)
    @filename = filename
  end

  def read_file
    File.readlines(@filename).map.with_index {|l, i|
      next "read #{@filename} at #{i}" unless l.start_with?('File:')
      FileReader.new(l.gsub('File:', '').chomp).read_file
    }.join("\n") << "\nEOF"
  end
end

puts FileReader.new('File1').read_file
```

or just

```
def File.read_recursively(filename)
  readlines(filename).map.with_index {|l, i|
    next "read #{filename} at #{i}" unless l.start_with?('File:')
    read_recursively(l.gsub('File:', '').chomp)
  }.join("\n") << "\nEOF"
end

puts File.read_recursively('File1')
```

Comment: Your answer is much cleaner than mine and a much better example of Ruby. I should have taken a few moments to refactor.

Comment: After playing around with some file IO I would strongly recommend against just using readlines. It does some really funky stuff when I tried it without the File in front of it. Like it was looking at the last file I tested for existence using the ARGV array instead of the string I passed it. Very weird. Put "File" in front of it and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that something in your rewriting code has obfuscated the problem.  Yes, those instance variables should be local to the instance.

Watch out for things where a block of code or conditional may be returning a value and assigning it to the instance variable...  for example, if your open statement uses the next block and returns the filename somehow... @filename = open(line) {}

I say this because the filename obviously didn't change back after the EOF

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It's not pretty but I tried to stay as close to your code as possible while Ruby-fying it too.

file_reader.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
class FileReader

  attr_accessor :filename, :lineNumber

  def initialize(filename)
      @filename = filename
      @lineNumber = 0
  end

  def read_file
    File.open(@filename,'r') do |file|
      while (line = file.gets)
        line.strip!
        @lineNumber += 1
        if line.match(/^File/)
          FileReader.new(line).read_file()
        end
        puts "read #{@filename} at #{@lineNumber} : Line = #{line}"
      end
    end
    puts 'EOF'
  end
end

fr = FileReader.new("File1")
fr.read_file
```

And the File1, File2, and File3 looking like:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
File2 
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
Line 11
```

Output:

```
read File1 at 1 : Line = Line 1
read File1 at 2 : Line = Line 2
read File1 at 3 : Line = Line 3
read File2 at 1 : Line = Line 1
read File2 at 2 : Line = Line 2
read File2 at 3 : Line = Line 3
read File2 at 4 : Line = Line 4
read File3 at 1 : Line = Line 1
read File3 at 2 : Line = Line 2
read File3 at 3 : Line = Line 3
read File3 at 4 : Line = Line 4
EOF
read File2 at 5 : Line = File3
read File2 at 6 : Line = Line 6
read File2 at 7 : Line = Line 7
read File2 at 8 : Line = Line 8
EOF
read File1 at 4 : Line = File2
read File1 at 5 : Line = Line 5
read File1 at 6 : Line = Line 6
read File1 at 7 : Line = Line 7
read File1 at 8 : Line = Line 8
read File1 at 9 : Line = Line 9
read File1 at 10 : Line = Line 10
read File1 at 11 : Line = Line 11
EOF
```

To reiterate we really have to see your code to know where the problems is.

I understand you thinking it has something to do with variable scoping so the question makes sense to me.

For the other people. Please be a little more kind to the novices trying to learn. This is supposed to be a place for helping. Thank you. </soapbox>